# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.logger is undefined - TeamsProvider.handleAuth() in @microsoft/mgt

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I am using the MS Teams tab application and Azure active directory to authentication. when the popup window appears, it returns "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.logger is undefined" from,

`TeamsProvider.hanldeAuth()`

error is thrown from below code line

```
(UserAgentApplication.prototype.urlContainsHash(window.location.hash)) {
     // the page should redirect again
     return;
}
```

**my code is as below**

*Index.js*

```
import * as MicrosoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js/dist/MicrosoftTeams";
import { Providers, TeamsProvider } from '@microsoft/mgt';

const config = {
    clientId: '<CLIENT_ID>',
    authPopupUrl: '/auth'
}
//TeamsProvider 
TeamsProvider.microsoftTeamsLib = MicrosoftTeams;
Providers.globalProvider = new TeamsProvider(config);
```

*Route*

```
<Router>
      <Route exact path="/auth" component={redirect-component}/>
      <Route exact path="/" component={login-component}/>
</Router>
```

*Login (login-component)*

```
async loginMethod() {
    const provider = Providers.globalProvider;
    if (provider && provider.login) {
        await provider.login();
        if (provider.state === ProviderState.SignedIn) {
           console.log("loginCompleted")
        } else {
           console.log("loginFailed")
        }
    }
}
```

*'/auth' component*

```
import * as MicrosoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js/dist/MicrosoftTeams";
import {TeamsProvider} from '@microsoft/mgt';

class Authentication extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        TeamsProvider.microsoftTeamsLib = MicrosoftTeams;
        TeamsProvider.handleAuth();// This is where error occured
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Redireact Auth URI
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I belive the issue with urlContainsHash() could you please try to set the [redirect uri in Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/teams#configure-redirect-uris)?

Comment: I have set the redirect URI in the azure portal properly. but the issue still remains. as of now, I am using MSAL Provider to achieve authentication, but in future, I will need to use TeamsProvider which provides a pop-up window to both sign-in/out.

Comment: I have exactly the same error using TeamsProvider. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @TechWatching, Please try to import MicrosoftTeams as follow [import * as MicrosoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js"] instead of [import * as MicrosoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js/dist/MicrosoftTeams"] which is in microsoft documentation seems not working. that might solve your problem.